# Public static final variable with getter

Tags: java, interface

at work we do a peer review of code and I found something I don't like and I want to ask about best practice for this particular problem.

We have an interface:

```
public interface Item {
    public String getType();
    //some other methods
}
```

and an implementing class:

```
public class EmailItem implements Item {  
    public static final String TYPE = "email";

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }
}
```

and some code that uses the classes:

```
for (Item item : items) {
    if (EmailItem.TYPE.equals(item.getType())) {
        isProcessed = Processor.process(item);
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Unknown failover type received to process. Type: {}", item.getType());
    }
}
```

At this point we have only one implementing class so checking the type is not necessary but we will add some other implementations and then it would make sense (though `switch` will be used).

The main issue is that `EmailItem` has variable `TYPE` set as public and this variable has also a getter.

Both class and instance of that class should have access to this variable, but having it `public static final` and accessing it with instance directly doesn't seem right/best practice (although it is technically possible) and when it would be private (as it should) then it won't be accessible from other classes (where `for` cycle is and static would not make sense at that point).

Through discussion we come up with solution with usage of `instanceOf(...)` or `instance.getClass().getName()` and `EmailItem.class.getName()` but none of them seem elegant to me :).

So finally, my question is what is the most elegant solution for described problem?

Heh, this is my first question here and I hope it makes sense to you ;).

Comment: Are you looking for the `instanceof` operator?

Comment: Why is TYPE a String rather than an enum?

Comment: As I posted I am aware of instanceOf(), but I am looking for programmatical clean solution.

Comment: As far as i know, the instanceof operator should be the most clear one

Comment: @sycho what is instanceOf()?

Comment: Why do you need to know the type? in most cases proper use of inheritance and polymorphism negates the need for such a value. Secondly, there is nothing wrong with `public static final`

Comment: Why can't you always use it as a `static` variable? So, why do you need the getter too?

Comment: @immibis sory that is caused by wrong syntax in my head :)

Comment: @meskobalazs It should make the code more readable as you use EmaiItem.TYPE it should evoke a constant but if you use item.getType() it should evoke getting a variable (though it is a constant).

Comment: How is masking a `static` to look like a property is more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you did it is fine, if you want to do it that way:

- The `static final` variable `TYPE` lets you treat it as a type constant,
- The implementation on the instance lets you check the constant against the return value on the interface.

However, when you find yourself dispatching on a type represented by `String` or some other value, you are usually going down a wrong path of `switch` statements in object-oriented code. If you have a choice of action at this point, consider an alternative technique of double dispatch, such as implementing the [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
interface ItemVisitor {
    void visitEmail(EmailItem item);
    void visitSms(SmsItem item);
}
interface Item {
    void accept(ItemVisitor v);
}
class EmailItem implements Item {
    public void accept(ItemVisitor v) { v.visitEmail(this); }
}
class SmsItem implements Item {
    public void accept(ItemVisitor v) { v.visitSms(this); }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
class Example implements ItemVisitor {
    public void visitEmail(EmailItem item) {
        // Do something with an e-mail
    }
    public void visitSms(SmsItem item) {
        // Do something with an SMS
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        for (Item item : ItemSource.getManyItems()) {
            item.accept(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about it from an OO point of view I'd consider the following approach:

```
public interface Item {
    public boolean process();
    //some other methods
}

public class EmailItem implements Item {  
    @Override
    public boolean process() {
        // email specific implementation
    }
}

public class AnotherItem implements Item {  
    @Override
    public boolean process() {
        // another implementation
    }
}

for (Item item : items) {
   isProcessed = item.process();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all "types" for your `Item` are known at compile time, you could use an enum like this:

```
public interface Item {
    enum ItemType { MAIL, OTHER; }

    public ItemType getType();
    //some other methods
}
```